# Spring boot 3 and Spring 6 with Tomcat 9

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have not found the answer I want on the web so I've decided to ask it here.  Apologize if this breaks any rules, etc.

We're trying to upgrade some of our java applications to spring boot 3 and spring 6.  The question is, will these apps still work with Tomcat 9?

These apps are currently running spring boot 2, spring 5 and Tomcat 9.

Comment: No, packages are different which are breaking changes. When using spring boot 3, or Spring 6, requirements are Tomcat 10 and JDK17.

Comment: @zawarudo Thank you.  Seems like that's the way it must be done.  I

Answer (score 4):

Based on this, Tomcat 9 won't work with Spring 6.  So, moving to spring 6 will requrire going to Tomcat 10.

https://devm.io/spring/spring-framework-6-release

> The sixth major version of the Spring Framework has been released,
> with Spring Boot 3.0 to follow at the end of November. Spring
> Framework 6.0 requires a minimum of JDK 17 at runtime, as well as a
> minimum of Tomcat 10/Jetty 11.

Comment: Yes, I have a theory that they did this so that projects will stop being legacy. In my company, we are doing an update of the same, and we will have to retire even an XML configuration, which in my opinion is pretty nice. After 15 years of product, we will no longer have 10 years old code.

Comment: Which gradle plugin supports deployment of web application into embedded tomcat server just like com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.7.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

For Spring 6 you compulsory need Tomcat 10.1.x(10.1.0 to 10.1.18) on 10.1.18 tomcat spring 6 + Java 17 runs fine.

You need JDK 17 or above versions for Spring 6(jakarta EE 9) + Tomcat 10.1.x.
https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/16/spring-framework-6-0-goes-ga
Note: Don't be stuck on Java EE 8, make the leap to the jakarta namespace, ideally straight to the Jakarta EE 10 level! The upcoming Spring Boot 3.0.0 release includes corresponding managed dependencies for you.

It all is depending on servlet spec and spring support:
Servlet spec 6.1 needs tomcat 11.x JDK 21 or later
Servlet spec 6 needs tomcat 10.1.x JDK 11 and later
Servlet spec 5 needs tomcat 10.0.x JDK 8 and later
Servlet spec 4 tomcat 9.0.x JDK 8 and later

Comment: FYI: Spring 6 + Tomcat 10.1.18 and Java 21 also works fine. (If upgrading from Spring 6 + Tomcat 10.1.18 and Java 17 )